# Fetch Multiple Recordset Using MySQLi Object

Tags: php, mysqli, recordset

I am trying to return multiple recordset using a stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `multiple`()
BEGIN    
    SELECT * FROM account;
    SELECT * FROM admin;    
END$$
```

When i hit CALL multiple() in the mysql UI like SQLYog then i get the result in separate tab for each recordset. But when i try to call this stored procedure in my php script that is using mysqli connector then i just get the first recordset.

Here is my php script:

```
<?php
// New Connection
$db = new mysqli('localhost','root','','db_test');

// Check for errors
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
 echo mysqli_connect_error();
}
echo "<pre>";

// 1st Query
$result = $db->query("call multiple()");
if($result){
     // Cycle through results
    while ($row = $result->fetch_object()){
        $user_arr[] = $row;
    }
    // Free result set
    $result->close();
    $db->next_result();
}
print_r($user_arr);
```

How we can get the second recordset using mysqli object?

Comment: Call $db->next_result(); once more?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use prepared statements:

Create procedure:

```php
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `multiple`()
BEGIN    
    SELECT * FROM account;
    SELECT * FROM admin;    
END $$
```

Fetch multiple recordset in PHP:

```php
//connection
$mysqli = new mysqli('hostname','username','password','db_name');

// Check for errors
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
   echo mysqli_connect_error();
}

//prepare statement
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("call multiple()");

//run statement
$stmt->execute();

//fetch all recorsets returned by procedure

$recordset_Counter = 0;

while ( $stmt->more_results() )
{
   echo "Recordset($recordset_Counter) : <br/>";
   $res = $stmt->get_result();

   //fetch all records from current recordset
   while( $row = $res->fetch_assoc() )
   {   print_r($row); echo "<br/>";  }

   $stmt->next_result();
   $recordset_Counter++;
}
```

Comment: How prepared statement is related to this?